# nullpointer exception on statement = conn.createStatement();

Tags: java, android

I am using jdbc in android (Aware not recomended)

I have following piece of code:

```
 public int CheckUser(String uName,String password)
        {

             try {

                    String sql="select uid from UserMaster where username='"+uName+"' and password='"+password+"'";
                    statement = conn.createStatement();
                    resultSet = statement.executeQuery(sql);
                    int value=0;
                    if (resultSet.next()) {
                         value=resultSet.getInt(1);
                        }


                    return value;

                }
                catch (Exception e) 
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    return 0;
                }
}
```

I gets null pointer exception on  `statement = conn.createStatement();`

**Logcat:**

```
09-12 11:04:14.543: W/KeyCharacterMap(483): No keyboard for id 0
09-12 11:04:14.553: W/KeyCharacterMap(483): Using default keymap: /system/usr/keychars/qwerty.kcm.bin
09-12 11:04:51.173: W/System.err(483): java.lang.NullPointerException
09-12 11:04:51.194: W/System.err(483):  at com.example.messagesql.gaSQLConnect.CheckUser(gaSQLConnect.java:69)
09-12 11:04:51.213: W/System.err(483):  at com.example.messagesql.Login$UserLogin.doInBackground(Login.java:109)
09-12 11:04:51.213: W/System.err(483):  at com.example.messagesql.Login$UserLogin.doInBackground(Login.java:1)
09-12 11:04:51.225: W/System.err(483):  at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:185)
09-12 11:04:51.233: W/System.err(483):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:306)
09-12 11:04:51.233: W/System.err(483):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
09-12 11:04:51.253: W/System.err(483):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1088)
09-12 11:04:51.253: W/System.err(483):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:581)
09-12 11:04:51.264: W/System.err(483):  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1019)
```

Plz help.

I tried declaring Statement object locally but no effect, still error persists.

Code of my file which calls this function:

```
public class Login extends Activity {


    public static String resp = "";
    public static String name = "";
    String username;
    String password;
     EditText etLoginID;
    EditText etPassword;
    final DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(this);

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);



        List<Contact> contacts = db.getAllContacts();
        if(contacts.size() != 0){
            for (Contact cn : contacts){
                resp = cn.getID();
                name = cn.getName();
            }
           // Intent i=new Intent(getApplicationContext(),Message.class);
            //startActivity(i);
        }

        etLoginID=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.etName);
        etPassword=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.etPassword);

        Button btnLogin =(Button)findViewById(R.id.btnLogin);

        final gaSQLConnect con=new gaSQLConnect();

        btnLogin.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                con.setConnection("AndroidDB", "sa", "ok");


                    username=etLoginID.getText().toString();
                    password=etPassword.getText().toString();
                    String[] values=new String[2];
                    values[0]=username;
                    values[1]=password;
                    UserLogin ul=new UserLogin();
                    ul.execute(values);



                    //Intent i= new Intent(getApplicationContext(),Messages.class);
                    //startActivity(i);


            }
        });


    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.login, menu);
        return true;
    }


    private class UserLogin extends AsyncTask<String[], Void, String>{

        final gaSQLConnect con=new gaSQLConnect();
        String[] values;
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String[]... params) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            values=params[0];
            String result=null;
            int uid;
            db.deleteContact(new Contact(resp));

            if (!values[0].isEmpty() && !values[1].isEmpty())
            {

                uid=con.CheckUser(etLoginID.getText().toString(), etPassword.getText().toString());


                return Integer.toString(uid) ;

            }
            else{
                uid=0;;
            }
            return Integer.toString(uid) ;
        }


    protected void onPostExecute(String result){            

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),result, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            db.addContact(new Contact(result, values[0]));
            Intent i=new Intent(getApplicationContext(),Messages.class);
            startActivity(i);

    }   
    }
```

Above is the code of file from which i calls the function.

In this onClick method of login i have setted connection.

Then also why it does not persists through whole application?

Whole code of DBConnection class:

```
public class gaSQLConnect 
{
    String url ="";
    Connection conn=null;
    Statement statement=null;
    ResultSet resultSet=null;




        public ResultSet getMessages(int uid)
        {


          try
          {
            String sql="select  mid,uid,message,rstamp from MessagesMaster where uid='"+uid+"' aand rstamp = 0 order by tstamp desc";
            statement = conn.createStatement();
            resultSet = statement.executeQuery(sql);
            return resultSet;
          }
          catch(Exception ex)
          {

          }
        return resultSet;

        }


        public void setConnection(String DBName,String UserName,String Password)
        {
            try {
                Class.forName("net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
                url ="jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://10.0.2.2:1433;instanceName=14GRAFICALI\\MSSQLSERVER2008;DatabaseName="+DBName+";integratedSecurity=true;user="+UserName+";password="+Password+"";
                conn =DriverManager.getConnection(url);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                }
        }
        int recFound=0;
        public int CheckUser(String uName,String password)
        {

             try {
                 Statement statement=null;
                    ResultSet resultSet=null;    

                    String sql="select uid from UserMaster where username='"+uName+"' and password='"+password+"'";
                    statement = conn.createStatement();
                    resultSet = statement.executeQuery(sql);
                    int value=0;
                    if (resultSet.next()) {
                         value=resultSet.getInt(1);
                        }


                    return value;


                  /*  if (value > 0) {
                        recFound = 1;
                    } else {
                        recFound = 0;
                    }
                    if (recFound > 0) 
                    {
                        return true;
                    } else {
                        return false;
                    }*/
                }
                catch (Exception e) 
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    return 0;
                }
}

        public void UpdateMessage(String[] mlst) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            try
            {
                String sql="update messagesmaster set rstamp = 1 where mid in (" + mlst + ") ";
                statement = conn.createStatement();
                statement.executeUpdate(sql);

            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {

            }
        }
}
```

Comment: This is about as clear of an exception as you can possibly hope for. You need to work on your fundamentals if it isn't obvious why you'd get a NullPointerException here, and why moving the declaration of `statement` has no effect. You should investigate why `conn` is null.

Comment: You need to create a Connection object before you run this bit of code - you're not managing to do this.  It's not clear whether you're trying to do create a Connection or not. If you are trying to, please post the code where you try, so that we can help you determine why a Connection is not being created.

Comment: @DavidWallace sir will you plz check my edit?

Comment: So are you actually calling setConnection from anywhere?

Comment: yes, i am calling it from onClick of loginpage...and also calling checkuser method from login page.

Comment: So I would suggest using a debugger to find out whether it is actually getting called when you expect it to be, and to find out why `conn` is not actually being set.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As the exception trace says your `conn` object is null and hence calling any method on it will cause `NullPointerException`. You need to check your code where you are initializing your `conn` object to initialize it properly. Also it is always a good practice to put a null check to avoid null pointer exception.

Comment: @ You are setting the connection properties in setConnection method, which is OK. But you need to have one getConnection method to return the conn object. Also make sure that setConnection is called once and later u just get the connection at other places using getConnection method.

Answer (score 2):

your database connection is null. But you are trying to create a statement. So only you got the `nullPointerException`

```
if(conn != null)
```

and then proceed

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is that you're calling `setConnection` on ONE `gaSQLConnect` object, then calling `CheckUser` on a DIFFERENT `gaSQLConnect` object, which has a different copy of the `conn` variable.  Stop creating so many `gaSQLConnect` objects.

Answer (score 2):

use connection creation only once.
If you are trying to pass any int value for success full connection rather Connection object , will get this error.

Answer (score 1):

Whenever you are trying to create a statement that the **Connection** must not be null and if it is null then you have to check this

```
if(conn!=null){

//Create statement

{
```